# iOS Facebook passwordless login

Tags: ios, facebook, webview

I have to provide Facebook integration to an app that is mostly hybrid in its design ... i.e, most of the code is written as html5 pages (bundled with the app). I would prefer using the webview method of login to Facebook, but it appears that if I do use the webview method as opposed to using Facebook SDK for iOS, the user will have to enter a password every-time.

Can someone verify if my understanding is correct. This is what is I could gather from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial:

**Embedded WebView Login Dialog**

...

**Advantages:**

...

**Disadvantages:**

Web-based dialogs tend to be slower.
People have to fill in their login credentials every time they go through the login flow.
Special considerations:

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample app embedded with Facebook login awhile ago too. Yes, web-based dialogs tend to be slower. However, the user don't have to login their credential every time they go through it. As I tested, the user will just need to enter their info for the first time login only. Nevertheless, the user will need to login when his/her session finish. Please refer to Facebook API docs about how long is the session.

I hope this answer your question somehow. Cheer.